# PL/SQL WHEN OTHERS THEN error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, exception, oracle12c

I am writing a simple procedure which should INSERT a row in a table and UPDATE all others with the same foreign key afterwards. My problem is WHEN OTHERS THEN statement. SQL Developer is giving me this error:

> Error(26,3): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WHEN" when expecting
>   one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for
>   goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with 
>         << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open
>   rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge
>   The symbol "exception" was substituted for "WHEN" to continue.

My procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INS_RETUR 
(
  P_BRDOKUMENTA IN RETUR.BrDokumenta%TYPE, 
  P_DATKREIRANJA IN RETUR.DatKreiranja%TYPE,
  P_DATSTAMPANJA IN RETUR.DatStampanja%TYPE,
  P_SIFRJ IN RETUR.SifRJ%TYPE,
  P_BRRADKNJIZ IN RETUR.BrRadKnjiz%TYPE,
  P_PRIJEMNIBR IN RETUR.PrijemniBr%TYPE,
  P_BRPORUDZBENICE IN RETUR.BrPorudzbenice%TYPE,

  P_REZULTAT OUT NUMBER
)
AS 
BEGIN
  P_REZULTAT := 0;
  P_PORUKA := 'Ok';

  INSERT INTO Retur
  VALUES (P_BRDOKUMENTA, P_DATKREIRANJA, P_DATSTAMPANJA, P_SIFRJ, P_BRRADKNJIZ, P_PRIJEMNIBR, P_BRPORUDZBENICE, 'A');

  UPDATE Retur
  SET Status = 'N'
  WHERE BrPorudzbenice = P_BRPORUDZBENICE
  AND BrDokumenta != P_BRDOKUMENTA;

  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    P_REZULTAT := 1;
    P_PORUKA := (-10001,'Doslo je do greske - '||SQLCODE||' -GRESKA- '||SQLERRM);
END INS_RETUR;
```

Why is this happening?

Also - do I have to RAISE this error in order to rollback, or this will be done automatically when code reaches WHEN OTHERS THEN statement? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing an `EXCEPTION`:

```
BEGIN
...
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    P_REZULTAT := 1;
    ...
END;
```

The error message is useful in this case:

> Error(26,3): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WHEN" when expecting
>   one of the following: ( begin case declare end **exception** exit for goto
>   if loop ...

Answer (score 2):

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:1155066278457

http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2017/02/now-not-to-handle-exceptions.html

You should NOT be using WHEN OTHERS in this case at all - at least not for apparent purpose.

This is viral behavior that seems to have caught on over the years.

There are too many non-data related errors that can happen in pl/sql that should result in a program crashing to prevent broken referential integrity.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INS_RETUR 
(
  P_BRDOKUMENTA IN RETUR.BrDokumenta%TYPE, 
  P_DATKREIRANJA IN RETUR.DatKreiranja%TYPE,
  P_DATSTAMPANJA IN RETUR.DatStampanja%TYPE,
  P_SIFRJ IN RETUR.SifRJ%TYPE,
  P_BRRADKNJIZ IN RETUR.BrRadKnjiz%TYPE,
  P_PRIJEMNIBR IN RETUR.PrijemniBr%TYPE,
  P_BRPORUDZBENICE IN RETUR.BrPorudzbenice%TYPE,

  P_REZULTAT OUT NUMBER
)
AS 
BEGIN
  P_REZULTAT := 0;
  P_PORUKA := 'Ok';

  INSERT INTO Retur
  VALUES (P_BRDOKUMENTA, P_DATKREIRANJA, P_DATSTAMPANJA, P_SIFRJ, P_BRRADKNJIZ, P_PRIJEMNIBR, P_BRPORUDZBENICE, 'A');

  IF SQL%ROWCOUNT <= 0 THEN
     [DO SOMETHING, MAYBE SOME MESSAGING, MAYBE SKIP THE UPDATE?]
  END IF;

  UPDATE Retur
  SET Status = 'N'
  WHERE BrPorudzbenice = P_BRPORUDZBENICE
  AND BrDokumenta != P_BRDOKUMENTA;

  IF SQL%ROWCOUNT <= 0 THEN
     [DO SOMETHING, MAYBE SOME MESSAGING]
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    P_REZULTAT := 1;
    P_PORUKA := (-10001,'Doslo je do greske - '||SQLCODE||' -GRESKA- '||SQLERRM);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);
    RAISE;
END INS_RETUR;
```